# Intellij undo changes in Resolve Conflicts window

Tags: intellij-idea

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-conflicts.html

When I click ">>" or "x" for a line to merge how do I undo that? For example, I'll go through a whole file merge and accidentally click ">>" on the wrong side. I don't know how to undo a single line, so I have to abort the entire merge and start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. It will simply undo your last change.

Just tested it in a diff viewer (with `>>`). Not tested if it works with conflicts when you press `X`.